# Middle binomial coefficient generator mod p

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

**Does there exists for all prime $ p $ an integer $ n $ such that $ {2n \choose n} $ is a generator modulo $ p $?**

Up to now, I could only check that small values of $ p $ indeed work.

Note that this is equivalent to asking whether all integers are congruent to some $ {2n \choose n} $ modulo $ p $ as:

- $ 2 \mid \displaystyle{4 \choose 2} $ and, for every $ p \ne 2 $, $ p \mid \displaystyle{p \choose \frac{p - 1}2} + {p \choose \frac{p + 1}2} = {p + 1 \choose \frac{p + 1}2} $
- Lucas Theorem ensures that binomial coefficients form a closed group under multiplication modulo any prime.

Maybe Wilson Theorem ($ (p - 1)! \equiv -1 \mod p $) might be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **true**. As stated above, middle binomial coefficients form a subgroup of $ (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z, *) $ because of Lucas Theorem.

For $ p = 2 $, take $ {0 \choose 0} = 1 $.

For odd $ p $, let's prove by induction that $ {2 \choose 1}, \dots, {2n \choose n} $ generate $ [\![1, 2n]\!] $ as long as $ 2n < p $:

$ \bullet $ **Initialisation**: For $ n = 1 $, we indeed have $ {2 \choose 1} = 2 $ and
$$ {\overline{2\dots 2}^p \choose \overline{\underbrace{1\dots 1}_{p - 1 \text{ times}}}^p} \equiv {2 \choose 1}^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \mod p $$

$ \bullet $ **Induction**: Suppose $ {2 \choose 1}, \dots, {2n - 2 \choose n - 1} $ generate $ [\![1, 2n - 2]\!] $ for $ n \ge 2 $. We have
$$ 2n - 1 = \frac n2\frac{2n \choose n}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1} \text{ and } 2n = 2\cdot n $$
Knowing that $ 2 $ and $ n $ are generated by $ {2 \choose 1}, \dots, {2n - 2 \choose n - 1} $ because $ 2, n \in [\![1, 2n - 2]\!] $, we find that $ 2n - 1 $ and $ 2n $ are generated by $ {2 \choose 1}, \dots, {2n \choose n} $, as wanted.